# Setting up trac with PostgreSQL - How to set encoding to UTF8?

Tags: debian, postgresql, trac, encoding, utf-8

So I've been looking to install [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) on my debian server with [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/). I setup everything as per the docs but when trying to run `trac-admin /path initenv` I get this error for database encoding:

`DataError: character 0xe282ac of encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "LATIN1"`

From further reading (and after seeing all my databases are set to encoding "LATIN1") it seems I need to change to UTF8, but how can I do this?

If I create my database like so:

```
createdb -U user -O user -E UTF8 trac
```

I get:

```
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding UTF8 does not match server's local en_GB
DETAIL: The server's LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding LATIN1.
```

It looks like it should be easy to fix by changing the encoding but after searching for a bit I have no idea how to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be you database cluster have LATIN1 locale. When you are setting cluster, you can add `--locale` parameter - see [this document](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/locale.html) for more informations. Your databases will be created according to this parameter.

Some locale parameters you can set in the configuration file. For example my settings from `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`:

```
lc_messages = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8'                     # locale for system error message strings
lc_monetary = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8'                     # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8'                      # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'cs_CZ.UTF-8'
```

Comment: I used apt-get install to install PostgreSQL so I never initialised any clusters myself. It wont let me run init.db because I get permission deined. If I try as root it also refuses.

Comment: You have to drop cluster and init a new one. And you have to do it under `postgres` user, or your postgres will not start. See `pg_lsclusters`, `pg_dropcluster` and `pg_createcluster` commands (and theire's man pages eventually). Or you can set your system locales to the en_US.UTF-8 (or somethink like it) and then do `apt-get install` for postgresql.

Comment: Thanks. I had to run `pg_dropcluster` first before running initdb.